# Laravel nova keeps throwing exception Route [nova.login] not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I've already posted this to `https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues` sadly hadn't got any love from there, so I'd like to know if anyone experienced this issue and how they resolved it.

- Laravel Version: 5.7.27
- Nova Version: 1.2
- PHP Version: 7.2.12
- Operating System and Version: MacOS 10.13.6
- Browser type and version: Chrome (Latest) FireFox (Latest)

#### Description:

Whenever I access my nova route in /admin <-- (this is where my nova resides) I get this exception thrown from`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php` line 389, `throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.")`, my nova was installled correctly and currently I don't have any other existing app routes this is a fresh install of laravel and fresh install of nova.

It was working fine until I introduced the custom path.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

1. Change the `'path' => '/admin'`
2. Run `php artisan config:clear` or `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: The title of your question mentions "nova.login", but the body of your question says "{$name}".  Is the error you're seeing mentioning nova.login?

Answer (score 0):

Check your NovaServiceProvider.php and make sure it has `withAuthenticationRoutes()` in the `routes()` function like this:

```
protected function routes()
{
    Nova::routes()
            ->withAuthenticationRoutes()
            ->withPasswordResetRoutes()
            ->register();
}
```